# Scottish idiom for people talking too much

Tags: idiom-requests, scottish-english

I'm trying to find a Scottish colloquial idiom that means that people talk too much (especially in a gossipping, hot air, or inconsequential way). Perhaps this might be along lines of the English 'more babbling than a brook in flood'.

I'm ideally after an idiom, not a single word.

Comment: When you say a "Scottish colloquial idiom" do you mean an idiom in English at originates in Scotland or are you after a [Scots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scots_language) idiom?

Comment: Does your 'idiom' tag preclude single-word answers?

Comment: My mother always used "[could talk the hind legs off a donkey](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/24247/142476), but that link shows it was from Irish Gaelic, but she was from the Scottish Gaelic culture so it maybe can just pass as Scottish?

Comment: "Haud yer wheest" = shut up you're talking too much

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> ***If patter wis water you'd droon***. Translation: “*If your conversation was water you would drown. Meaning: You talk too much.*”

From [Guide To Scottish Sayings](https://matadornetwork.com/read/scottish-slang/)

Comment: From the same source: *Don’t pronounce your Ts. Any self-respecting Scot would never dream of uttering (u-erring) a “T” in the middle of a word. See “butter” (bu-er) and “water” (Wa-er).*

Comment: Self-respecting Scot who pronounces his `T`s, not like those uncouth Glasgow-area glottal-stoppers. However, if uttering a phrase in the Scottish language, I do adopt a Glasgow-like accent and wa-uer my pa-uer.

Comment: Ken, as a non-native speaker of English, I'm wondering if there's a feeling among Scots from further up north than Glasgow that Glasgowers might be too influenced by "English English"? Also, it would be lovely to be able to hear the phrase spoken in both ways!

Comment: This reminds me of the Hungarian saying "if laziness were painful, you'd be screaming". Not at all the same meaning, of course, but same construction.

Answer (score 12):

I suggest **blether**. From [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/blether)

> *Scottish* a variant spelling of [blather](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/blather)

which in turn gives

> If someone is blathering on about something, they are talking for a long time about something that you consider boring or unimportant.

---

Additionally [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/clishmaclaver) has

> **clishmaclaver**
> <sub>NOUN</sub>
> *Scottish*
> idle talk; gossip

Comment: This is the correct word. Also see https://www.scotsman.com/news/scottish-word-of-the-week-blether-1567604 for an enhanced discussion.

Comment: I use that as a less uncouth version of "shooting the shit" - "having a good old blether down the pub with my pals", for instance. It's never had negative connotations for me.

Comment: @KenY-N but "shooting the shit" isn't a Scottish idiom.

Answer (score 5):

I'm used to ***clatter*** as a noun, meaning ***racket, loud noise***. But I found this in [the full Oxford English Dictionary<sup>1</sup> definition for the verb...](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/33925?rskey=Z20Klv&result=4#eid)

> Verb: **clatter** 3a (intransitive)
> To talk rapidly and noisily; to talk idly; to chatter, prattle, babble.
> **In modern Scottish, to tattle, talk scandal.**

Given that reference to"modern Scottish", I can't explain why the most recent cited use is...

> 1816 W. Scott, Antiquary *- Ye may be sure it was clattered about in the kitchen.*

---

<sup>1</sup> In fact, I found ***clatter*** in close proximity to ***tittle-tattle*** by searching Google Books for texts containing both those terms, which turned up [*Wilson's Tales of the Borders and of Scotland : historical, traditionary, & imaginative : **with a glossary**.*](https://www.abebooks.co.uk/book-search/title/wilsons-tales-borders/author/wilson/first-edition/) But I couldn't get at the actual definition there, so I went to the full OED instead.

Answer (score 5):

There's also **to haver**, to palaver, to talk nonsense, to go on and on about something.

https://youtu.be/tbNlMtqrYS0

Comment: Saw "to haver", knew instantly what the YouTube link was :)